# Is there an event that is fired when HoT puts a cell into edit mode?

Tags: handsontable

I'd like to alter a cell's data, but only when it enters "edit" mode. There are a lot of events I can use, `onSelectionByProp` seems close but it's firing too often to be useful. Let's say, for instance, that I want to add '*' to a cell that has a value that is invalid in some way, but only when that cell is about to be edited. OK, it's a silly example but it's easier to explain that than what I'm actually doing.

My current approach (haven't done it yet) is to find `TD.current` when a cell is double-clicked and then alter the text directly. Ideally I'd like to find a "retrieve data" event and alter what's coming back from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onEditBegin is a proposed event for future version.

[See here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events) for list of events

Comment: `onEditBegin` is only proposal for the event. If you want to made this feature faster - add your thoughts here: https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/628

Answer (score 2):

You can map `keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress` or `change` event from jQuery for `.handsontableInputHolder` element in a page. Is a textarea in which user enter data, so this is your 'edit mode' for handsontable.